# При переключении страницы сбрасывается фильтр формы

Tags: python, django

У меня есть такая функция во views.py:

```py
def paneli_v_v(request):

    paneliv = PanelV.objects.all()

    form = PanelVFilterForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['min_price']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data['min_price'])
        if form.cleaned_data['max_price']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(price__lte=form.cleaned_data['max_price'])
        if form.cleaned_data['burners_count']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(burners_count__exact=form.cleaned_data['burners_count'])
        if form.cleaned_data['cooking_panel_type']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(cooking_panel_type__exact=form.cleaned_data['cooking_panel_type'])
        if form.cleaned_data['brand']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(brand__exact=form.cleaned_data['brand'])
        if form.cleaned_data['color']:
            paneliv = paneliv.filter(color__exact=form.cleaned_data['color'])

    page = Paginator(paneliv, 20)
    page_list = request.GET.get('page')
    page = page.get_page(page_list)
    context = {'form': form,
               'page': page}

    return render(request, 'catalog_pvv.html', context)
```

А так выглядит шаблон HTML:

```html
<div class="catalog-filter">
<form action="", method="get">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Показать">
</form>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row row-cols-4">
    {% for panel in page.object_list %}
  <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="{% url 'panel' panel.id %}">
          <img src={{panel.image.url}} class="card-img-top" alt={{panel.name}}>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">{{panel.name}}</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Артикул: {{panel.article_number}}</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">{{panel.price}} Руб.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination ">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{% url 'pvv' %}?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for num_page in page.paginator.page_range %}
    <br />
    {% if page.number == num_page %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link active" href="{% url 'pvv' %}?page={{ num_page }}">{{ num_page }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{% url 'pvv' %}?page={{ num_page }}">{{ num_page }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    <br />
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{% url 'pvv' %}?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Так выглядит форма фильтра:

```py
class PanelVFilterForm(forms.Form):
    TypeOfCookingPanel = ((None, '---'), ('Газовая', 'Газовая'), ('Электрическая', 'Электрическая'), ('Индукционная', 'Индукционная'), ('Комбинированная', 'Комбинированная'))
    BurnersCount = ((None, '---'), (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'), (6, '6'), (8, '8'))
    Brand = ((None, '---'), ('Lex', 'Lex'), ('Graude', 'Graude'), ('Kuppersberg', 'Kuppersberg'), ('Teka', 'Teka'))
    Color = ((None, '---'), ('Бежевый', 'Бежевый'), ('Белый', 'Белый'), ('Кремовый', 'Кремовый'), ('Бордовый', 'Бордовый'), ('Бронза', 'Бронза'), ('Золото', 'Золото'), ('Коричневый', 'Коричневый'), ('Красный', 'Красный'), ('Медь', 'Медь'), ('Серебристый', 'Серебристый'), ('Серый', 'Серый'), ('Фиолетовый', 'Фиолетовый'), ('Чёрный', 'Чёрный'), ('Нержавеющая сталь', 'Нержавеющая сталь'), ('Антрацит', 'Антрацит'))
    min_price = forms.IntegerField(label='Цена от', required=False)
    max_price = forms.IntegerField(label='Цена до', required=False)
    burners_count = forms.ChoiceField(label='Количество конфорок', choices=BurnersCount, required=False)
    cooking_panel_type = forms.ChoiceField(label='Тип варочной панели', choices=TypeOfCookingPanel, required=False)
    brand = forms.ChoiceField(label='Бренд', choices=Brand, required=False)
    color = forms.ChoiceField(label='Цвет', choices=Color, required=False)
```

Я так понимаю, что в URL страницы между именем страницы и номером страницы нужно подставить строку фильтра, а как это сделать - не могу понять. Во всех гайдах как-то по-другому фильтруют, может я не корректно использую форму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел решение, прошу оценить на сколько оно колхозное)

решение заключается в том что я в href прописал сборную солянку из ключей и значений каждого поля формы следующим образом

```
href="{% url 'pvv' %}?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}&{% for field in form %}{{ field.name }}={{ field.value }}{% if not forloop.last %}&{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```